# Elsa + docker weird JavaScript errors

Tags: docker, elsa-workflows

I am trying to test out ELSA workflows via the docker container as outlined in https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/quickstarts/quickstarts-elsa-and-docker

The container runs fine, but when I try to click the first tab, I get this..
[image]

When I click workflow registry the page comes up, but when I click "Create Workflow" I get this...[image]

Do they just have a broken copy of the docker image they have uploaded broken or do I have something misconfigured?  This is in the latest version of chrome BTW.

Comment: What if you click "**Create** Workflow"?

Comment: Ultimately, you should post this issue to Github since only the developers would know the answer

Comment: When cross-posting, please make sure to cross-link as well: https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/issues/1606

Answer (score 0):

As @onecricketeer pointed out, this looks like an issue with the docker image you're using.

The Docker images are built from the `master` branch, which can sometimes include a hickup.

I recommend to pull a new version of the image, and if you are still seeing the issue, it is most likely a bug.

In that case, you will consider opening an issue.